# Getting an error in Android studio when integrating the Helpshift API (null pointer exception)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, helpshift

I'm getting a null point exception in Android studio. I'm trying to integrate Helpshift into my current app. The null point is being called on the help button I think. The error I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 
'void com.helpshift.CoreApi.updateApiConfig(java.util.Map)' on a null object reference
```

My code looks like

```
package com.example.leoconnelly.connexus;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton FindCareButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


//THE PURPLE BUTTON!!!!!!!
    FindCareButton = (findViewById(R.id.find_care_button));

    FindCareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openFindCare();
        }
    });

    /*
    GetStartedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openSearchActivity();
        }
    });
     */

    ImageButton helpButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton13);
    helpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ApiConfig.Builder configBuilder = new ApiConfig.Builder();
            configBuilder.setRequireEmail(true);
            configBuilder.setEnableTypingIndicator(true);
            com.helpshift.support.Support.showConversation(MainActivity.this, configBuilder.build() );


        }
    });


}

public void openFindCare () {
   Intent mainActivityToFindCare = new Intent (this, 
HealthCenterListActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainActivityToFindCare);
}

}
```

I'm not exactly sure what it's pointing too. I'm trying to open FAQs from Helpshift.

Comment: Seems like you missed something. Just follow the [Sample](https://github.com/helpshift/helpshift-android-sdk-examples) and [Documentation](https://developers.helpshift.com/android/getting-started/).

Comment: I know I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `InstallConfig` for the API. Try adding it in the Calling Activity.

```
import com.helpshift.Core;
import com.helpshift.All;
import com.helpshift.InstallConfig;
import com.helpshift.exceptions.InstallException;

Core.init(All.getInstance());
        InstallConfig installConfig = new InstallConfig.Builder()
                .setEnableInAppNotification(true)
                .build();

        try {
            Core.install(getApplication(),
                    API_KEY,
                    DOMAIN,
                    APP_ID, installConfig);


        } catch (InstallException e) {
            android.util.Log.e("Helpshift", "install call : ", e);
        }
```